# My controller wont print out a list on my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to get it to print out my Linked List from the user input. This code adds the object to the linked list as I can see it being printed to the console but they are not being printed to the page. Thanks.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addr")
public class AddressController {

    public Collection<Address> addresses = (Collection<Address>) Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<Address>());

    /*  @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String getAddressForm() {
        System.out.println("Test"); 
        return "addressProject/addressBook";
    }
    */
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public ModelAndView submitForm(String name, String email, String group,   String phoneNumber, String address){

        Address addr = new Address(name, email, group, phoneNumber, address);
        addresses.add(addr);
        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("addressProject/addressBook");
        modelandview.addObject("addresses", addr);

        System.out.println("Address: name=" + addr.getName() + ", email=" +    addr.getEmail() + ", group=" + addr.getGroup() + ", phoneNumber=" + addr.getPhoneNumber() + ", address=" + addr.getAddress());

        return modelandview;    
    }
}
```

JSP:

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<form>


Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<br/>
Group: <input type="text" name="group"><br>
<br/>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"><br>
<br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
<br/>
<input type="submit" />

</form>
 </div>

    <h2>Addresses v5</h2>

<c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="address"> 
 <tr>
    <td>${address}</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: You're not generating valid HTML there.

Comment: Sorry, how should it look?

Answer (score 1):

You add the address to the model and not the list:

```
modelandview.addObject("addresses", addr);
```

should be:

```
modelandview.addObject("addresses", addresses);
```

jsp.

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="address"> 
 <tr>
    <td>${address}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<table>
```

And ensure you have declared the taglib directive at the top of your JSP file:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed this but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Post full jsp source.

Comment: Here is the full [jsp](http://pastebin.com/ziBDSF4y). When I changed the JSP you provided to <table>
<c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="addresses"> 
 <tr>
    <td>${addresses}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<table> it seems to print the whole list out.